# I am getting an error with Calendar1_SelectionChanged Event Handler

Tags: c#, webforms

I want to take the selected date from the calendar control and pass to the argument.

EventArgs does not contain a definition for Start

```
 protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                _availebletimeSlotsRoom1 = new BindingList<string>(_allTimeSlots.ToList());
                _availebletimeSlotsRoom2 = new BindingList<string>(_allTimeSlots.ToList());
                _availebletimeSlotsRoom3 = new BindingList<string>(_allTimeSlots.ToList());
                _availebletimeSlotsRoom4 = new BindingList<string>(_allTimeSlots.ToList());
    
                DLAvailTS1.DataSource = _availebletimeSlotsRoom1;
                DLAvailTS2.DataSource = _availebletimeSlotsRoom2;
                DLAvailTS3.DataSource = _availebletimeSlotsRoom3;
                DLAvailTS4.DataSource = _availebletimeSlotsRoom4;
    
                UpdateRoom(1, e.Start, _availebletimeSlotsRoom1);  //ERROR HERE:'EventArgs' does not 
                 contain a definition for 'Start' and no extension method 'Start' accepting a first 
                 argument of type 'EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an 
                 assembly reference?)
                UpdateRoom(2, e.Start, _availebletimeSlotsRoom2);
                UpdateRoom(3, e.Start, _availebletimeSlotsRoom3);
                UpdateRoom(4, e.Start, _availebletimeSlotsRoom4);
            }
```

Comment: EventArgs does not have a field or property 'Start'.  If you are trying to get 'Start' from the calendar object, cast the sender to the calendar object type and access the 'Start' property/field there.

Comment: @hijinxbassist, I am new to programming C#/webforms. Do you have an example of a casting of the sender to calendar object type?

Comment: The safer way to cast an object is to use the 'as' keyword.  If the object being cast is not that type, it will be null instead of throwing an invalid cast exception.  var calendarObj = sender as Calendar;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This procedure starts after some change of the selected dates in the Calendar1 control. Parameter 'e' have not property Start. You read start date from property of Calendar1 control.
Is Calendar1 control class MonthCalendar? Then you use value from property SelectionStart.
Example:

```
UpdateRoom(1, Calendar1.SelectionStart, _availebletimeSlotsRoom1);
```

Comment: No Calendar1 is not control class MonthCalendar, as the MonthCalendar control is not available in the webforms toolbox. MonthCalendar is only available in the windows forms toolbox.